# Why is this integrator unstable?

Tags: operational-amplifier, stability, integrator

I am trying to convert an acceleration signal to a velocity signal using an integrator. After building the circuit, it turned out to be unstable: With no signal at the input (`Buff_Az` sits at a constant voltage of about 0.9 V), the output of U3B oscillates between 0 V and 3.3 V (supply voltage) at a frequency of about 0.7 Hz.
The point marked `V_165` is connected to a resistor divider (2 x 100k) and a 0.1 uF capacitor to 0 V, generating a 1.65 V reference.

What could be causing this instability?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you made a 60 dB AC gain into an oscillator due to R7C11 with insufficient phase margin from stray inductance.   There are limits to converting to velocity with SNR,  but it appears you have more noise and too much gain than signal.

Comment: U3B has a voltage gain of 10M/10k= 1000 times at low frequencies. The 3.3V power supply or the 1.65V voltage divider might be modulated by the opamp current and need a higher bypass capacitor value. Try reducing the value of R7 to reduce the extreme amount of low frequency gain.

Comment: Connect C22 to gnd and see if you get the same oscillation using a smaller cap like 0.1uF

Comment: 26mV, Ignoring the implications of C13 in the input source (since I don't know what that is) what I may see is (1) U3A voltage follower (buffer); (2) C12 differentiator (differential of acceleration, which is 'jerk'); (3) U3B high-voltage-gain integrator (with slow lagging reset of C11 via R7). So you are integrating 'jerk' to get back 'acceleration' (less the integral of some unknown DC offset.) Where's the velocity, exactly?

Comment: 26mV, I am guessing that you feel C12 provides DC removal prior to integration. But it is also a differentiator.

Comment: Connect a signal; don't leave it open circuit - bias it up to some dc value.

Comment: @Audioguru: You may be right. It improves with a larger capacitor, but the 1.65V still varies at the same frequency as the oscillator. I will focus on getting a more stable reference

Comment: @jonk: Yes, the goal of C22 is DC removal. I would say it may work as a differentiator at very low frequencies (that's why it removes DC), but at higher frequencies the response is dominated by R8, and the differentiating effect disappears

Comment: @26mV I am refusing to look at the specific values for a reason, keeping this discussion at a high level. (Obviously, at some point, that has to change. But it's really your problem and not mine.) So, let's continue. So you agree that C22 is a differentiator, but at low frequencies, and provides DC removal. That's also where the integrator operates -- at low frequencies.

Comment: @26mV Ignoring the middle-band, and focusing on the two extremes you have: (A) a differentiator, plus an integrator, which yields the integral of the derivative and because of the initial derivative function removes DC bias; or, (B) not a differentiator but now an HF pass element, plus now an HF opamp follower, which effectively ... well... just follows. (In between may be where interesting and more complex things can happen. But I don't see you moving to take that middle ground, just yet.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My educated guess: It's the terrible power supply rejection ratio of this circuit. It's got a maximum voltage amplification of 1000. Your input voltage is fixed, yet the 1.65V reference voltage depends on the power supply. Therefore it amplifies changes in the power supply voltage by a factor of 1000, so that a 3.3mV change in VCC already drives the amplifier into saturation.

Are you sure that your power supply (and therefore your 1.65V reference) is **that** stable? You should really use a dedicated, stable reference chip to generate your 1.65V.

Comment: I think you're onto something. The 3.3V is pretty stable, but not the 1.65V, showing little spikes in sync with the oscillation. I managed to improve it with a larger capacitor (10uF), and worked OK for a few seconds but it started to oscillate again, and I still get some minor variations in sync with the oscillation. I will try to get a voltage reference for the 1.65V.

Comment: OK, so I found the problem, and it was along the lines of what was discussed in this question. The problem is that the output of the integrator is connected to other analog blocks. One of those has a differential input resistance of ~8Mohms (as per data sheet), and the other input is connected to (you guessed it) V_165. This is like the output of the integrator was connected to V_165 through an 8M resistor, and because V_165 is also connected to the + input of the integrator, I had a positive feedback path. Lesson learned: buffer your references. Thank you to all who brought your ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to get some resource that covers analog computer circuits, like Philbrick's palimpsest. Start with something that works, and go from there - changing the op-amp type from a typical +/-15V-powered model to a lower voltage one, etc. For the particular op-amp you're working with, I'd suggest a symmetric +/-1.5V supply from two AA batteries. Only once you have a working circuit with a low ground impedance, convert it to a high impedance ground, and see if it still works. That way you can ensure that at each step your understanding of the circuit matches the reality.

Accurate integrators require capacitors that cost more than a digital reimplementation of this circuit would cost - with a precision 16-18bit ADC, DAC, and an MCU in the middle to integrate digitally. Look at [general purpose analog computers that were actually produced](http://www.analogmuseum.org/english/collection/): their integration capacitors are *large* (on the order of a cubic inch of volume), and require very low dielectric absorption, and very low leakage. An electrolytic integrator capacitor will "work", but be rather disappointing and you may need to screen/select the parts to ensure they provide enough precision. I'm not sure what your goal is - it would help to know that. It is certainly possible to find excellent low-leakage aluminum electrolytic capacitors that approach film capacitors in terms of leakage and noise: it'll be a job in itself, though, and datasheets won't help you.

Back to your circuit: Since you have nothing to prevent C12 from charging up, the effective input to the integrator is arbitrary at DC, and depends solely on the bias current flowing into R8. Add a resistor across C12 to ensure a 0V initial condition by discharging it. Initially use 1k so you don't have to wait (tau<0.1s), later this can be increased to get the time constant larger than what you need.

**Always ensure that there's a DC input path to an amplifier's input!**

What you'll be left with is a 1000x amplification of U3's offset voltage and 1/f noise that dominates in your frequencies of interest. Since MPC6L04 has about 1mV of typical offset voltage, the output will be "typically" between 0.6 and 2.6V. If the part you got is less than typical, the output will be saturated. The 1/f noise on top of it will be ~10mVpp at the 20s time scale. At 3V full scale, that's ~0.3% worth of noise, or about 8 bit noise-free bits. But you won't be able to use 3V full scale in practice, so it'll be even worse.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you get unintended oscillation, examine any source of positive feedback ( with AV+>=1)

This IC had 90 deg of phase margin as an integrator has +ve FB from somewhere . Eliminate the possibilities of coupling to Vin+ and return currents , reactive coupling , then look at supply dips with output and high gain. (PSRR)

Answer (score 0):

Many op amps have a maximum capacitive load on their output before they become unstable; you're giving this one a 10 nF load, since the integrating capacitor is connected between the output and the virtual ground. Check section 4.3 (page 13) of [the datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/MCHP_S_A0010037118_1-2521310.pdf).

Microchip recommends putting a small resistor in series with the output for stability if the capacitive load is more than 100 pF. You can try that, but it would affect the accuracy of the integration. If that's not something you can tolerate, try looking for an op amp rated for higher capacitive loads. Ones that can handle particularly high capacitances may call that out in their datasheet's specifications section, rather than hiding it deep in the application information like this one does. And beware of datasheets that say something along the lines of "stable with large capacitive loads", because you don't know what they consider large!

Comment: I doubt it's the 10nF capacitor. That cap isn't a capacitive load since it's only connected to an actual AC ground via a 10k resistor (to U3A's output). At high frequencies, the capacitor's impedance drops, connecting the OpAmp's output to its inverting input, effectively turning it into a voltage follower, which is a stable configuration. C11 therefore can't make the circuit unstable, no matter how big it is.

Comment: I think Jonathan is right. I don't think the output of the op amp sees a 10nF capacitance load